# Have you ever done SQL injection?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-injection

I want to know if you have ever performed injection on a website using SQL injection for ethical hacking.

What tricks/techniques have you have used (especially mysql)?

Comment: For ethical or unethical purposes?

Comment: actually ethical, making a site more secure. but i think techniques do not differ for an ethical or unethical hacker.

Comment: @Rahim, I hope you realize that a honest answer here is more likely an admission of guilt of breaking into a system, and exposure to unlimited liability. Do you really think that anybody would come up with their "tricks" as an answer to this question?

Comment: Also I believe this should be community wiki *at least*.

Comment: @rahim your reason is nonsense. Knowing attack techniques will not help you make a site more secure. Defense technique is always the same and do not depend on the attack technique. So it cannot be ethical. Learn SQL if you are so curious.

Comment: @Col i believe that best attackers are best defensers

Comment: I think the question is valuable, if made community wiki and only to highlight what are the most common scenarios (like the % wildcard searches) as an exercise of self-awareness

Comment: You are WRONG. Best attackers are crazy asocial swindlers. While best defenders are ones who is able to remember a few very simple rules.

Comment: @Chubas, well, the question is valuable to certain users. But I must say it is poorly worded and does not reflect the intent of OP to use the answers in a legal context.

Comment: @Chubas it cannot be valuable because defense is simple and completely irrelevant to attack.

Comment: @Vineet Again: it cannot be ethical because **defense is irrelevant to attack**. there can be ten thousands attack techniques but every one of them would be in vain if you follow only two simple rules: use parametrized query and hardcode every other dynamic query part in your script. Better teach local folks these 2 unsophisticated rules than dig on this smelly topic

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, I disagree partially. Ethical hacking might be required in cases where parameters are not bound to the query, and where user input has to be concatenated. Not a lot of applications do this, but for the ones that do, testing does help in verifying that the app is not susceptible. An example is the following query- SELECT TOP(**n**) FROM tbl; , where **n** is user input.

Comment: @Vineet if parameters are not bound there are 2 simple rules again: escape strings and cast numbers. **still nothing complicated** to learn. And TESTING is not collecting tricks.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, again I have to disagree. It can be just strings. SELECT blah FROM tbl ORDER BY **col**; where **col** is user input. And testing is the only way for an auditor to declare compliance, without having access to source (which is often the case for COTS). Unfortunately, in the real world, a tick in the box is still needed.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds as I have said already, **hardcode every other dynamic query part in your script.** Hardcode it. And choose from previously defined variants. Not a rocket science again, sill the same simple rules. And TESTING is not collecting tricks. Single vulnerability can be used in thousands ways. Thus, collecting these thousands **cannot help to learn how to defend** or test, **only one is enough**. That's why this questions smells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used the standard trick on login forms:

```
user: admin
pass: ' OR '1'='1
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of counter measures can be taken?

Comment: @diamandiev no need to use any special counter measures at all. Good built application is already invulnerable to this silly "attack"

Comment: To answer my self. Use parameters and/or stored procedures: UserPassword = @Password

Comment: Thilo, yes. Not in my own code, but when checking others'. I've worked for a web hosting provider and when someone hacks a website the customer always blames us first, even though the above SQL injection often works. Trying standard SQL injection attacks before checking their code often saves a lot of time :-)

Answer (score 6):

Not directly, but sometimes I do LIKE searches with wildcards (%) even though the search page does not say it supports them.

Comment: I think Neopets once acknowledged that this trick worked with some of their search boxes. Or at least they didn't mind fan sites showing that it works.

Answer (score 5):

If you intend to perform ethical hacking or penetration testing of applications using MySQL, you'll find the [OWASP Testing Guide, specifically the section on MySQL](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_MySQL) to be of immense value, apart from the generic [Testing Guide for SQL injection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_%28OWASP-DV-005%29).

Note that this does not make any assumptions about the framework or langauge in use - PHP, Java (including Java EE, Spring etc.), so it is pretty generic in how SQL injection may be attempted against an application. The actual techniques involved in getting the user inputs to the database access layer of the application, indeed will vary from one application to another. Applications that parse HTTP requests, will of course, require all inputs (URL parameters, name-value pairs in the POST body, HTTP headers) to be suspect. Having a different source of input (say XML or JSON instead of simple HTTP requests) will require you to feed in SQL in appropriate manner that will be understood by the application's parsers, eventually resulting in transportation of SQL to the layer where database queries are executed.

Answer (score 2):

Nice infomation about techniqs for

Example :

```
 statement = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '" + userName + "';"
 pass userName = ' or '1'='1
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '' OR '1'='1';
```

[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Type of it

```
1.2 Incorrect type handling
1.3 Vulnerabilities inside the database server
1.4 Blind SQL injection
 1.4.1 Conditional responses
 1.4.2 Conditional errors
 1.4.3 Time delays
```

Answer (score 0):

You just remimded this, I hope you'll find it fun:
http://xkcd.com/327/ ;)

Comment: Little Bobby Tables moved to Norway - https://www.sysedata.no/nyheter/edvin-tables#english

Comment: "and figured we'd use the opportunity for some harmless - or so we thought - fun."
At least the companies who had to work with this company on their databases had to make a great sql anti-injection protection! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have used the basic methods like everyone else, but always on my own websites

```
' OR '1'='1
```

I even joined a site where you can learn the basics of hacking in a website, they have put up a serie of website specially made to show the vulnerability of the website (of course you are not shown how to do it but you have to find it out for yourself). And no I feel no guilt whatsoever as I do not use it to harm other peoples website but only myne.